# What to do when an app works fine debugging, but doesn't work in the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm in version 2.3 of an app I've had in the App Store for about a year and a half. Suddenly, I submit an update to the app store with a few small changes, and now when loaded from the app store, some images won't load on all devices. It is a consistent set of images on a scrollview- it all appears black instead, but there are other pages with fewer images that consistently still work and are implemented exactly the same. No memory warnings. No SDK/XCode/OS X upgrades since last updating the app.

There are a few messages logged to the console, and those print correctly and don't indicate any problems. No errors are logged.

I'm completely at a loss for how to debug this. I'm already getting angry emails about it. I don't have time to keep resubmitting and waiting a week for it to be approved. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wish you luck. This is honestly one of my greatest fear when submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check the case of your image names.
- Do a full rebuild of your app (ie Build->Clean).
- Do a fuller rebuild - delete the "build" and simulator folders
- Test on several real devices, of different generations and OS versions.
- Build an Ad Hoc distribution and test that.

Generally, image problems are caused by the OS not finding the image in the app's bundle.

This can be because the device is case-sensitive whereas the simulator is not, so something that works for the simulator might not work on devices.

Also the IDE can be a bit flaky (hence the full rebuild). For some reason, I've seen resources compiled into the app never get removed, even if I clean the build. The only way to fix this is to delete the build folders, and/or the simulator folders. Simulator folders are at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/` (or whatever your build version was). You can trash the build folders without worry, but don't delete too much in Application Support or else you might need to re-install XCode; just find the GUID (ABCDEF01-2345-6789-ABCD-EF0123456789) that matches your app.

An Ad Hoc build, especially if you base it off of your Release configuration, will probably be the closest thing to a real build that you can get. There are tricks to using the command-line codesign utility to take a release build and change its signature so that you can run it as an ad-hoc but that's definitely not low-hanging fruit.

Comment: I'm accepting this because these were all great things to try. It turned out to be a very subtle error on my part, although I'll never understand why it still worked before submitting.

Comment: I had changed the naming format for some image files, and changed the format string selecting them, but accidentally reverted it or undid it somehow. I can't believe how many times I checked that and missed the error. Anyway the images with the old names had been deleted and don't exist in the file system or bundle anywhere, but still could show up in the simulator and on the device while testing. Even after cleaning, they must have been cached somewhere.

Comment: Ya know, I think I ran into that once. The solution was to find the app folder in the Simulator directory and blow it away. Very annoying - once resources are added to the simulator bundle, they never go away.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all your image files are in your test app bundle and submitted app bundle, and not in subdirectories in your test app bundle, and that the upper/lower case and spelling of all file names is identical within all usages inside and outside the app.